# Debian/Ubuntu: Differences between apt-file find/search

Tags: debian, apt, apt-file

Is there a practical difference between these two commands?

```
/home/pkaramol/Desktop
$ sudo apt-file search logrotate.conf
logrotate: /etc/logrotate.conf
logrotate: /usr/share/man/man5/logrotate.conf.5.gz
petitboot: /etc/logrotate.d/petitboot/logrotate.conf
rsync: /usr/share/doc/rsync/examples/logrotate.conf.rsync
unicorn: /usr/share/doc/unicorn/examples/logrotate.conf

/home/pkaramol/Desktop
$ sudo apt-file find logrotate.conf
logrotate: /etc/logrotate.conf
logrotate: /usr/share/man/man5/logrotate.conf.5.gz
petitboot: /etc/logrotate.d/petitboot/logrotate.conf
rsync: /usr/share/doc/rsync/examples/logrotate.conf.rsync
unicorn: /usr/share/doc/unicorn/examples/logrotate.conf
/home/pkaramol/Desktop/centos_7
```

According to the help:

search|find                Search files in packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `man apt-file`:

`search` is

```
       Search in which package a file is included. A list of all packages
       containing the pattern pattern is returned.

       Since Contents files does not contain directories, the pattern must
       match (part of a) file name.

       By default, the search action interprets its pattern as if
       --substring-match was specified.
```

And `find` is

```
Alias for search.
```

So both are same.